# Como criar objetos (variáveis) com diferentes nomes dentro de um loop?

Tags: r, variáveis, loop

Quero gerar bases de dados distintas num loop. No exemplo abaixo seriam 3 bases distintas com os seguintes nomes: "dados1", "dados2", "dados3".

```r
for (n in 1:3){
  dados<-paste0("dados",n)
  dados<-runif(10,1,20)}
```

No entanto ao rodar o código só é gerado um objeto com o nome "dados" em vez dos três.

Como fazer para o R entender que eu quero atribuir os valores a objetos criados no loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `assign` para isso.

```r
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:3){
  nome <- paste0("dados", i)
  assign(nome, runif(10,1, 20))
}
```

A primeira parte `nome <- paste0("dados", i)` cria o nome da variável. A segunda parte `assign(nome, runif(10,1, 20))` atribui um valor à variável cujo nome será retirado de `nome`.

Escrevi a variável `nome` separadamente para explicar melhor a função, mas você poderia deixar o `paste` dentro do `assign` direto:  `assign(paste0("dados", i), runif(10,1, 20))`.